# Rename first half of all file names in a directorry before common string (hyphens to periods)

Tags: bash

I need to convert hyphens and underscores to periods for all files in a directory, but only for the first half of each file name. All files include the string **L001**, which is the point where I need periods before and underscores to remain after.
An example file name:

```
A1898-MYSE-M-HEE_S19_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
```

to

```
A1898.MYSE.M.HEE.S19_L001_R1_001.fastq.qz
```

The code I'm working with returns the following error:

```
line 4: fp: command not found
lp: Error - unable to access "=" - No such file or directory
line 6: new: command not found
mv: cannot stat '*L001*': No such file or directory
```

I put the following script in the same directory as the files and ran it:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd $1;
for file in *L001*; do 
  fp="${file%L001*}";  #first part
  lp="${file#*L001}";  #last part
  new="${fp//_/.}L001$lp";
  mv "$file" "$new";
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
for file in *L001*.fastq.gz; do  # iterates over the required files
    pre=${file%%L001*}  # strips off the portion after L001 (including)
    post=${file##*L001}  # drops the portion before L001 (including)
    echo mv -- "$file" "${pre//[-_]/.}L001${post}"  # replaces all `_` 
                                                    # and `-` with `.`
                                                    # in `$pre` and 
                                                    # rename using `mv`
done
```

Drop `echo` to do the actual `mv`-ing.

**Example:**

```
% for file in *L001*.fastq.gz; do pre=${file%%L001*}; post=${file##*L001}; echo mv -- "$file" "${pre//[-_]/.}L001${post}"; done 
mv -- A1898-MYSE-M-HEE_S19_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz A1898.MYSE.M.HEE.S19.L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
mv -- A1898_MYSE_M-HEE_S19_L001_R1_002.fastq.gz A1898.MYSE.M.HEE.S19.L001_R1_002.fastq.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

`rename 's/[-_](?=.*L001)/./g' *L001*`

This `rename` command applies the perl substitution regexp on all `*L001*` files and uses the input and respective output to rename files. The regexp replaces all hyphens and underscores -- followed by a lookahead `(?=…)` of any characters and `L001` -- with a single period.

You may need to install the `rename` package first, since it is none-essential.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am sure this would work as well as the first answer but I couldn't figure out how to install perl-rename easily.